# Python - Filtering based on top 5 appearing categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new data frame by filtering out the rows with the top 5 most appearing countries and saving it into a new dataframe.

I tried using .nlargest but it doesn't work for categorical data.

Thank you.

[Example of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQNcZ.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) - it return sorted `Series` by counts, so for top values filter `index` values by indexing and pass to [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
top5 = df['Country'].value_counts().index[:5]
df1 = df[df['Country'].isin(top5)]
```